# Wide angle picture in react-native

Tags: react-native, expo-camera, react-native-vision-camera

I created a new React Native project based on the expo-camera library. When I started the app on an iPhone 13, I noticed that the pictures taken with the camera appear very zoomed-in. I attempted to adjust the zoom level to achieve a wider angle picture using the zoom prop, but unfortunately, this didn't work as expected.

```
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
<Camera style={{ flex: 1 }} type={type} ref={cameraRef} zoom={0.5}>
```

Next, I tried using `react-native-vision-camera`, but encountered an error stating that it's not supported in Expo Go. Instead, it recommended using EAS/expo prebuilds by running `expo run:ios`. However, attempting to run the project with `expo run:ios` also resulted in an error.